# Node JS header problems with ionic

Tags: node.js, json, ionic-framework, frameworks

So i am using ionic framwork to make my app and using nodeJS as my backend but i am still a noob in this and i can't seem to figure it out still after 4 days so hopefully someone could answer this problem to me and why would be appreciated.

So for my ionic client side i do this to make a http.post request

```
 progress() {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = {headers: headers};
    let postData = {
        username: this.username,
        email: this.email,
        password1: this.password1,
        password2: this.password2
    };
    this.http.post('localhost:4000/api/users', postData, options,).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

and this is what i am doing to get the data from the server but that's not working

```
// Packages
let express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');


const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8100'}));
const port = 4000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Whenever you enter localhost:4000/ //
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send(('Server runs'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));


app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
res.send('api/users page');

request.get({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8100/create-account'
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log('error:', err); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
    console.log('statusCode:', res && res.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    res.send(body);
});
});
```

i also tried 'http://localhost:8100' & 'localhost:8100' 
so someone help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add a handler for your POST request**. To do this use [app.post](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.post.method), and it looks like this

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  // You can find your data here
  const data = req.body;
  console.log(data);

  // Send back a response
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```